# Error installing the Offline help in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with UpdatePack 2.

I've downloaded the Offline documentation and I've open the Microsoft Help Viewer 2 as Administrator (Run as Administrator). I've change the "Installation source" to Disk, I've selected the HelpContentSetup.msha and when I click the Update button I get the following error

[image]

Can someone tell me how to solve this?